# Snapshot WMI Query returns nothing

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, hyper-v, get-wmiobject

```
-> $VMs = Get-WmiObject -Class "Msvm_ComputerSystem" -Namespace "root\virtualization\v2"
-> $vm = $VMs[1]
-> Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\virtualization\v2" -Query "Associators Of {$vm} Where AssocClass=Msvm_ElementSettingData ResultClass=Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData"
```

I use it that way but it returns nothing. VM has 2 checkpoints. But returns nothing.

I know the following command but **need a query like above**. The following command runs without error.

```
-> Get-VM | Get-VMSnapshot
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Associators Of ${vm}` ?

Comment: @Theo no. the above usage is correct. Also, I tried your suggestion and I got an error.

Comment: Can you confirm that `$VM` isn't empty?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala  .Yes, I checked it but It isn't empty.

Comment: Does running it with the value alone, and not in a variable, make a difference? Meaning `Associators Of valuegoesHere Where AssocClass=Msvm_ElementSettingData ResultCla....`. I also feel like the wql syntax is wrong. Maybe double quote it all, with single quoting the where query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note: The commands below all requires Powershell to be running as an admin. If it's not, you'll always gets zero results, IMX.]

I either get no output or an error no matter how I write the query. This appears to be a pretty common problem with this class and namespace. Searching online reveals a lot of people with this problem. [This looked like the best overall example/workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a7c58caa-5efa-408f-bb73-5e72dd22f43c/hyperv-wmi-provider-v2-msvmresourceallocationsettingdata-class?forum=servervirtualization).

From that link, this does work:

```
$VMs = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -ClassName Msvm_ComputerSystem
$VM = $VMs[1]

# This returns several results
$VM.GetRelated('Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData')

# This returns one result
$VM.GetRelated('Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData','Msvm_SettingsDefineState',$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,$null)
```

I do not see the `GetRelated()` method documented in [the class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/msvm-computersystem), but I believe that it's inherited from [the ManagementObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.getrelated?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

---

That said, I can get a slightly different version working with the newer CIM cmdlets (see `Get-Command -Module CimCmdlets` on Powershell v5.1 or 7), and I would recommend using those anyways. `Get-WmiObject` was superseded by the CIM cmdlets in Powershell v3. One of the big benefits has been that you no longer need to deal with the obnoxious ASSOCIATORS OF syntax from WQL. You can just use `Get-CimAssociatedInstance`.

```
$VMs = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -ClassName Msvm_ComputerSystem
$VM = $VMs[1]
$VM | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData
```

The above works for me. On the plus side, this code will also work on Powershell v6 and v7, which don't have `Get-WmiObject`.